What is the best PROGRAM_ID for creating Liquidity pool on Raydium in Devnet?
I'm trying to create Liquidity pool on Raydium in Devnet.
But transaction always failes. With errorr:
Unknown Program (HWy1jotHpo6UqeQxx49dpYYdQB8wj9Qk9MdxwjLvDHB8)

It is realy to create liquidity pool in devnet?
Anf if it is realy, what is the rigth raydium program id for this?

Raydium Devnet addresses are at the Raydium docs site.
See How to create a liquidity pool on Raydium on Solana devnet? - I can't mark it as a duplicate because it's on regular Stack Exchange.

The program id to interect with Raydium devnet LP looks correct, you might need to take closer look in the the tx details, it should contain more information about the transaction failure.
Below is my working example for your reference.
const {
    Liquidity,
    MAINNET_PROGRAM_ID,
    DEVNET_PROGRAM_ID,
} = require('@raydium-io/raydium-sdk');
const BN = require('bn.js');

const {
    connection,
    makeTxVersion,
    CONFIG_PROGRAM_ID,
    myKeyPair,
} = require('../config.js')
const {
    buildAndSendTx,
    getWalletTokenAccount,
} = require('./util.js')

async function createPool(params) {
    const RAYDIUM_PROGRAM_ID = process.env.NETWORK == 'mainnet' ? MAINNET_PROGRAM_ID : DEVNET_PROGRAM_ID

    const myPublicKey = myKeyPair.publicKey

    /* do something with start price if needed */
    // const startPrice = calcMarketStartPrice({ addBaseAmount: params.addBaseAmount, addQuoteAmount: params.addQuoteAmount })
    // console.log("START PRICE")
    // console.log(startPrice)

    /* do something with market associated pool keys if needed */
    // const associatedPoolKeys = getMarketAssociatedPoolKeys({
    //     baseToken: params.baseToken,
    //     quoteToken: params.quoteToken,
    //     targetMarketId: params.targetMarketId,
    //     programId: RAYDIUM_PROGRAM_ID.AmmV4,
    //     marketProgramId: RAYDIUM_PROGRAM_ID.OPENBOOK_MARKET,
    // })
    // const poolId = associatedPoolKeys.id

    const initPoolInstructionResponse = await Liquidity.makeCreatePoolV4InstructionV2Simple({
        connection: connection,
        programId: RAYDIUM_PROGRAM_ID.AmmV4,
        // programId: CONFIG_PROGRAM_ID.AMM_OWNER,
        marketInfo: {
            marketId: params.targetMarketId,
            programId: RAYDIUM_PROGRAM_ID.OPENBOOK_MARKET
        },
        baseMintInfo: params.baseToken,
        quoteMintInfo: params.quoteToken,
        baseAmount: params.addBaseAmount,
        quoteAmount: params.addQuoteAmount,
        startTime: new BN(Math.floor(params.startTime)),
        ownerInfo: {
            feePayer: myPublicKey,
            wallet: myPublicKey,
            tokenAccounts: params.walletTokenAccounts,
            useSOLBalance: true // if has WSOL mint
        },
        associatedOnly: false,
        // computeBudgetConfig?,
        checkCreateATAOwner: true,
        makeTxVersion: makeTxVersion,
        // lookupTableCache?,
        feeDestinationId: CONFIG_PROGRAM_ID.CREATE_POOL_FEE_ADDRESS
    })

    const poolInfo = initPoolInstructionResponse.address
    const poolId = poolInfo.ammId

    const { innerTransactions } = initPoolInstructionResponse
    const txids = await buildAndSendTx(innerTransactions, { skipPreflight: true })

    console.log("Pool Created")
    console.log("Pool Create Tranasactions :", txids)
    console.log("Pool Address :", poolId.toString())

    return { poolInfo, poolId }
}

function calcMarketStartPrice(input) {
    return input.addBaseAmount.toNumber() / 10 ** 6 / (input.addQuoteAmount.toNumber() / 10 ** 6)
}

function getMarketAssociatedPoolKeys(input) {
    return Liquidity.getAssociatedPoolKeys({
        version: 4,
        marketVersion: 3,
        baseMint: input.baseToken,
        quoteMint: input.quoteToken,
        baseDecimals: input.baseToken.decimals,
        quoteDecimals: input.quoteToken.decimals,
        marketId: input.targetMarketId,
        programId: input.programId,
        marketProgramId: input.marketProgramId,
    })
}

module.exports = {
    createPool
};



The best option would be creating a CPMM pool.

In any case (AMM, CLMM or CPMM) the best program ID is chosen by the Raydium SDK or from the addresses list in official docs:(https://docs.raydium.io/raydium/protocol/developers/addresses)
To create a normal AMM, you require

create a market for your tokens and get market ID
create an AMM pool for the market
The deposit LP into that pool


But in a CPMM Pool it's very simple and can be done in a single step.
The cost for creating such a pool is around 0.15 SOL

Here is an example code for creating a CPMM pool:
https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-sdk-V2-demo/blob/master/src/cpmm/createCpmmPool.ts
